# How to evaluate $ \int_{0}^2 x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (5x-3)dx ~~ ?$

Tags: definite-integrals

How to evaluate $$ \int_{0}^2 x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (5x-3)dx ~~ ?$$
I have tried to evaluate, $$ I = \int_{0}^2 x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (5x-3)dx = 5\int_{0}^2 x^{27} (x-1)^{17} dx - 3\int_{0}^2 x^{26} (x-1)^{17} dx$$ by parts but I am getting very lengthy expressions for both the integrals . Please help.

Comment: Hint: You may split $(5x-3)=2x+3(x-1)$ and write $I=I_1+I_2$, Integrate $I_1$ such that $-I_2$  appears.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc By that way, answer would be zero, not $1.5 \times 10^7$

Comment: @AjayMishra the answer is not zero.

Comment: I know that, answer is latter one, approx.

Comment: That is mechanised in CASes, e.g. Mathematica answers $ \frac{134217728}{9}$ through  the command Integrate[x^26*(x - 1)^17*(5 x - 3), {x, 0, 2}] .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick, the numbers have been "arranged":

$$(x^{27}(x-1)^{18})'=27x^{26}(x-1)^{17}+18x^{27}(x-1)^{16}=(27(x-1)+18x)x^{26}(x-1)^{17}\\=9(5x-3)x^{26}(x-1)^{17}.$$

Comment: You could feel it by the fact that $27+1+17+1$ and $17+1$ are in the ratio $5:3$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $$ I = \int_{0}^2 x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (5x-3)dx = \int_{0}^2 x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (2x+3(x-1) )dx  = I_1 + I_2 $$
    Let us integrate $I_1$ by parts, taking $x^{27} $ as first function, therefore, $$ I_1 = \left . \frac{1}{9} x^{27} (x-1)^{18} \right| _{0}^{2}- I_2  ~ = \frac{2^{27}}{9} -I_2 $$
    Hence, $$ I = \frac{2^{27}}{9}~~ .$$

Comment: Thanks, it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^{a+1} (x-1)^{b+1} = x^a (x-1)^b \left\{(a+b+2)x - (a+1)\right\}$$

So
\begin{align*}
\int x^{26} (x-1)^{17} \left\{(26+17+2)x - (26+1)\right\} dx
&= \int x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (45x - 27) dx \\
&= 9\int x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (5x - 3) dx \\
&= x^{27} (x-1)^{18}
\end{align*}

Thus $$\int x^{26} (x-1)^{17} (5x - 3) dx = \frac{1}{9} x^{27} (x-1)^{18}$$